# Reason why dependent variables need to be interval type and independent variables need to be categorical type when finding differences in group means?

Tags: anova, categorical-data

Can someone explain the basics about why dependent variables need to be interval type and independent variables need to be categorical type when finding differences in group means?  The responses I get back from others I ask are "that's just the way it is" and "they just are" which don't really help me understand it.

Answer (score 2):

First, if your goal is comparing **group means**, you need **groups** and then calculate **means** for these **groups**. The groups are given by your independent variable (categories) and the mean (or averages) can only be calculate if that dependent variable contains data on an interval (continuous) scale, where intervals between values are interpretable. Otherwise, calculating the mean is not possible or wouldn't make much sense.

If your dependent variable is categorical, e.g. dead/alive, your sample estimates between groups would be expressed as proportions and not as means, which you could then use to test for differences.

Answer (score 0):

The independent variable represents your group identification, so those are categories. When you talk about the mean, you have to specify the mean of *what*. And usually you look at the mean of a continuous variable, like height or weight. This is most likely in the context of ANOVA. But in a broader sense, the dependent variable doesn't have to be continuous.